# Rasa-core, Slots not getting Populated

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am trying to create simple printer support chat bot using `rasa-core` via nlu interpreter, bot should get the printer model, and printer type and post a issue.

I have used the printermodel and printertype variable in slot and entity, but the slots are not getting populated from the chat string.

Please help me on this.

Comment: can you provide your stories.md and domain.yml?

Answer (score 2):

Not very much information to go off of, but here are several things I would check if my slots weren't being filled correctly:

- Is NLU parsing the entities correctly? Slots are usually filled from NLU entities. Send your text direct to the NLU and see if the entities are found.
- Entity and Slot names are not consistent? The default method of filling slots without custom programming expects the slot name to match the entity name.
- Are the slots defined correctly in the domain information?

If you're still having trouble I encourage you to [create an issue](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/issues) or join us on [gitter](https://gitter.im/RasaHQ/rasa_core).

Comment: Any sample pls ?

Answer (score 2):

For example, we have to design simple conversation

```
User: I am Shivam
Bot:  Hello Shivam
```

Here, we have to extract `name` and respond using it.

**Step 1:** In `nlu.md` file

```
## intent:told_name
- i am [shivam](name)
- my name is [shivam](name)
- hi, i am [shivam](name)
```

**Step 2** In `domain.yml` file

```
intents:
  - told_name

actions:
  - utter_greet

entities:
 - name

slots:
  name:
    type: text

templates:
  utter_greet:
  - text: "Hello {name}"
  - text: "Hello {name}, happy to meet you."
```

**Step 3** In `stories.md` file

```
# story_01
* told_name{"name": "Mayank"}
  - utter_greet
```

I think, you are missing someting in step 3

Comment: Hmm, not filling the slot , instead fills `None`